# Hiding a custom WPF button when the content is Null

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to hide the content of a button when the content is Null inside a style for a custom button.

Any help would be appreciated please.

My XAML:

```
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at my example. Your style is ok - maybe button content is not null and this is the cause why it's not working.

XAML code:

```
...
<StackPanel>
     <Button Content="Red" Height="50" Background="Red" Click="btnSetNull_OnClick" />
     <Button x:Name="btnYellow" Content="{x:Null}" Height="50" Background="Yellow">
         <Button.Style>
             <Style TargetType="Button">
                 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
                         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                     </Trigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
         </Button.Style>
     </Button>
     <Button Content="Blue" Height="50" Background="Blue" Click="btnSetNotNull_OnClick" />
 </StackPanel>
 ...
```

Code-behind:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub btnSetNull_OnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        btnYellow.Content = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSetNotNull_OnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        btnYellow.Content = "Yellow"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, my content was an empty string which I now convert to a Null which fixed the issue.